# Apache URL rewriting with ServerAlias

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, rewrite, serveralias

I have a vhost running on a CentOS 7 Server, which is serving 2 Prestashop stores.
In this vhost conf file, I have a ServerName and a ServerAlias, each directing to a dedicated store.

Recently I moved both stores to HTTPS, but one question remains: I know how to rewrite the URL to redirect  from HTTP to HTTPS, but can I redirect based on the URL asked by the client?

I know how to do it with 2 vhosts, but as the conf will be near identical, i wanted to do it with only one file.

Example: rewrite `http://store1.example.com` to `https://store1.example.com` AND `http://store2.example.com` to `https://store2.example.com` all in the same Vhost conf file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the HTTP_HOST variable that apache sets:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName store1.example.com
  ServerAlias store2.example.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put them in one or many files as you like, but the most straightfoward way to do this is with multiple `<VirtualHost>` directives:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName store1.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://store1.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName store2.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://store2.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName store1.example.com
    ServerAlias store2.example.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I admit I didn't think of this way to do it. Thanks for your answer!